# Calling functions defined inside Manipulate in other notebook?

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, notebooks, packages

I'm creating a notebook with a `Manipulate` and I'm trying to call/use a function from another notebook (I use `Get` for that), in which the function is also inside a `Manipulate`... but my "main" notebook wouldn't "see" that function.

I have also added `LocalizedVariables -> False` in the "slave" notebook, with no improvement. Of course I have created a package (*.m) from the "slave" notebook and put the right path for it in `Get`.

There must be some limitations, which I'm not aware of, of using this kind of calling functions from another notebook, right?

Example of (very simple) code:

Mfunction.nb (& Mfunction.m)

```
Manipulate[
func[a_, x_] := Sin[a*x];
Plot[func[a, x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}],
{a, .1, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

Mmain.nb

```
Manipulate[
Plot[1/func[b, y], {y, 1, 100}],
{b, 1, 20, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
Initialization :> (
Get["(* Path *)//Mfunction.m"];)]
```

Comment: The .nb and the .m are in the same folder, so the same path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Manipulate` is `HoldAll` and the body isn't evaluated till it is displayed. That's because effectively there is `Dynamic[body]`. I once explained that a little in [Manipulate in Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64748/5478).

So inside the package it won't do anything, as no output is generated. You can see this here:

```
ClearAll[x];

Manipulate[x = 5, {y, Null}];
Pause[1];
x

Manipulate[x = 5, {y, Null}]
Pause[1];
x
```

The first `x` doesn't have a value because `Manipulate` wasn't displayed (`;`).

---

The way to go is to move your definitions outside of a `Manipulate`.

A quick but not general fix would be to load those packages while temporarily hiding `Manipulate's` attributes. This can by done with `Block`:

```
Initialization :> (Block[{Manipulate}, Get@"../Mfunction.m"];)
```

---

At the end but you can read some tutorials about the package creation in documentation or here:

[Creating Mathematica packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29325/5478)

Comment: my goal is to re-use functions, already defined in some calculation tools I've created in Mathematica, without needing to re-define them in my new notebook or copy/paste the corresponding, available code in it. I also want to avoid to modify the code in the referenced notebooks, as they are already deployed in form of .cdf files. So as I understood, it's not possible to achieve this goal, right?

Comment: @Conrad no, it's not. You have to do something like: `func[a_, x_] := Sin[a*x]; Manipulate[Plot[func[a, x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}],{a, .1, 10, 0.1}]` but the you need `Savedefinitions` or something so that the old `Manipulate` will remember them.

Comment: @Conrad this is not general but will this work for you: `Block[{Manipulate}, Get @ path ]` instead of pure `Get`?

Comment: no, it doesn't work unfortunately. I tried both to put the `Block[]` section under `Initialization`and also directly at the beginning of `Manipulate`, without success...

Comment: @Conrad like: `Initialization :> (Block[{Manipulate}, Get["../Mfunction.m"]];)]`? Does .m file contain those `Manipulates` a all?

Comment: yes, actually I did `Initialization :> (Block[{Manipulate}, Get@"../Mfunction.m"];)` , but after that I also tried exactly as you write...

Comment: The .m file contains of course the `Manipulate` .

Comment: @Conrad don't have more time to check your setup but it seems to work in general: `(ClearAll[f]; Block[{Manipulate}, Get[#]]; Close[#]) & @ 
 StringToStream@"Manipulate[f[x_]:=1;x,{x,0,1}];"`

Comment: could you please put your proposal directly in my code? I don't really understand how to use it. After that I promise I will not bother you any longer on this topic ;-) .

Comment: @Conrad This is only a minimal example that blocking manipulate should work when you are using get on the package with functions inside manipulates. Don't worry about StringToStream stuff, it is there because I can't use Get on a string yet I wanted to create minimal example.

Comment: It works, I managed to make the main notebook "see" the function, by using the `Block[{Manipulate}, Get[path]]`. Thank you so much! Could you please put this solution in form of an answer, to be able to choose it accordingly?

Comment: @Conrad Great, done :)